# PDOException on acl:init in Symfony

Tags: symfony, exception, pdo, doctrine-orm, acl

I'm trying to initialize ACL in my Symfony app and I'm getting a mysql PDO Exception.

```
php app/console init:acl

  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Mysql is working fine in my app <strike>and I can do a doctrine:schema:update without any errors</strike>.

Here is the ACL condiguration:

```
security:
    acl:
        connection: default

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true
```

Database part of my config

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
        # e.g. database_path: %kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3
        # path:     %database_path%

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
```

Anyone have any idea what I can do to troubleshoot this?

Comment: can you update your question with the acl configuration

Comment: i assume your default connection is set in your config.yml? or it have another name? can i see database part in your config, you can remove the other things from security,yml from the question is fine only the acl part is important

Comment: I've updated with the doctrine section of my config. Not sure what else you'd need.

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with my local development environment and MAMP.

To solve this I changed my database_host to '127.0.0.1' (instead of localhost). Then, in MAMP I enabled "Allow network access to MySQL - only from this mac". After restarting MAMP, it worked.

Comment: well thats odd.. wonder how the same connection the default one which works in doctrine:schema:update and not acl, and never trust localhost :D

Comment: I was actually mistaken. I think I ran that command on the wrong machine to test.

Thanks for the help though and sorry for the misinformation :(